# PageBreak in converting HTML to doc and docx fromat - PHP

Tags: php, html, doc

I have converted HTML to DOC format using PHP.

kindly view the below screen shot.

[image]

My Problem is **i need to print 1st table in first page and 2nd table in second page.**

Here is my set of code.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");
echo $html = '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML TO WORD</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.table {
 page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
<body>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr>
<td height="105">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center; font-size:30px;color:#ed6500;"><b>Title</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center; color:#595959;">Author:
<span style="color:#9d402b; text-decoration:underline;">Author name</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Table Of Contents</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:30px;">Sub Category 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
```

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

put this where you need a page break:

```
<br clear="all" style="page-break-before:always" />
```

this is working for me

Comment: "page-break-before:always" seems to work on any element. But not "page-break-after:always".

Comment: When I add "page-break-before:always" to a container div Word seems to apply this on every single child element as well. It needs to be added to a child-less element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Page 1 contents:
<hr>
Page 2 contents:
<hr>
Page 3 contents:
```

and within CSS:

```
hr {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```